# Bash script to remove folders older than X, but skipping newest N... Compatible with special characters in path

Tags: bash, find, xargs, tail

I am writing a backup script in bash and want to delete all backups older than X days, while leaving at least the newest N backups.
This seems so simple, yet I have not been able to find a solution to the whole problem.

In my case, each backup consists of one folder, which are all in the same parent folder.
To decide which backups are the newest the created or modified date should be used. If this gets too complicated, I can also go alphabetically by filename (the folder names consist only of a constant part and a datestamp YYYYMMDD).
I want my script to work for any paths and folder names, so I cannot assume that they do not contain spaces, linebreaks etc..
And it is supposed to work on most modern linux system. Currently I am running it on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

I had a few different ideas, which all fall short in some way.

**Parameters I used**

```
target_basefolder="/path/to/backups/parent/folder"
min_n_backups=3
backup_keepdays=28
```

**Version A - Oneliner**

I tried this:

```
find ${target_basefolder}/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -rz | xargs -r0 rm -rf
```

But I do not know how to tell it to ignore the newest three results. I tried to put `tail -n +$((min_n_backups+1))` in there, but could not find a way to tell `tail` to use NUL as seperator instead of newline (like the -0 option for xargs).

**Version B - Two Parts**

Count the folders first and then run the delete command only if there are enough newer backups.

```
n_backups=$(find ${target_basefolder}/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime -$(backup_keepdays) -printf '.' | wc -m)
if (( $n_backups > $min_n_backups )) ; then
    find ${target_basefolder}/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +$((min_n_backups+1)) -print0 | sort -rz | xargs -r0 rm -rf
fi
```

The problem here is that it will not delete anything if there are not enough newer backups present. For example if min_n_backups is 3 and there are only 2 backups newer than backup_keepdays, it will not delete any of the maybe 100 older backups instead of leaving just 1 of them and deleting the rest.

**Version C - Simple Loop**

Go through backup folders one by one and check their date.

```
icount=1
for ifolder in $(find ${target_basefolder}/* -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -rz ) ; do
    is_old=$(find "$ifolder" -maxdepth 0 -type d -ctime +$((min_n_backups+1)) -printf '.' | wc -m)
    if (( $icount > $min_n_backups && $is_old > 0 )) ; then
        rm -rf $ifolder
    fi
    ((icount++))
done
```

I have yet to test this, especially with paths containing spaces and linebreaks. I am not sure if the for loop can handle a NUL-separated list. And if I can give `find` a folder name with spaces/linebreaks as input.
But it feels overly complicated anyway, so I hope I won't have to go there.

**Version D - Brute Force**

I had the idea to move the newest N backup folders to a different folder, then deleting the folders older than M, then moving the newer N folders back. This could get slow if the folders are big. And it does not feel "right" somehow...

I hope someone can help me solve my Version A or give me hints on the other versions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many filenames?

Comment: If your `coreutils` is newer than 8.25 (2016-01-20) inclusive, `tail -z` will be available to use NUL as a delimiter.

Comment: @jhnc By filenames you mean folders? Could be any number.

Comment: @tshiono Thank you, that's what I was looking for! Not I still have to figure out how to filter by date AFTER applying the tail... Forgot about that in the original post.

Comment: Code efficiency is not important with 10 or 100 filenames to process but may be more important with 10,000,000 filenames.

Comment: I see. In my case, it won't ever be above 100 so readability is more important than efficiency. At the moment I'd be happy about anything that works though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `tail -z` is available, would you please try:

```
# count the number of directories newer than $backup_keepdays (forced to remain)
keep=$(find "$target_basefolder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime -"$backup_keepdays" -printf "." | wc -c)

# take MAX($keep, $backup_keepdays)
(( keep > min_n_backups )) && min_n_backups=$keep

# keep $((min_n_backups+1)) directories from the top in the sorted list
find "$target_basefolder" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -rz | tail -zn +$((min_n_backups+1)) | xargs -0r rm -rf --
```

A small tip: replace `xargs -0r rm -rf --` with `tr '\0' '\n'` to print the
directories to be removed as a dry run.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! Also for the tip with tr, that helped a lot!
Just one question though: Why do you use "wc -c" (counting bytes) for counting the dots? I would have used "wc -m" (counting characters). Are there downsides?

Comment: And a second question: What is the double dash for? Is it a failsafe for filenames beginning with dashes? Or does the command not work without it?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
As for the options to `wc`, both `wc -c` and `wc -m` work in the same way in this case.
The case which makes the diffefence will be the multi-byte character.
For instance, `echo -n "☺" | wc -c` outputs `3`, while `echo -n "☺" | wc -m`
results `1`.
As for the second question, you are right. `--` is a failsafe for filenames
beginning with dashes. It will work well without it in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this with appropriate error checking:

```
(
    cd "$target_basefolder" &&
    stat --printf '%Y/%n\0' -- */ |
    sort -rnz |
    gawk -F/ 'NR>m && $1<b { print $2 }' \
        RS='\0' \
        ORS='\O' \
        m=$min_n_backups \
        b=$(date +%s -d "-${backup_keepdays} days") |
    xargs -0 -n1 echo to remove:
)
```

Choose appropriate `stat` field to check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This might be cleaner to some people than the answer I chose, but the other used commands I'm already familiar with so I feel more comfortable with it. I appreciate your help though!

Comment: my main point is that `*/` is much more elegant than a convoluted `find` if you only need to process a single small directory of files. `stat` probably isn't very portable but if you have GNUish utilities, you probably have it (and `-z`). GNU `find`'s `-printf` has similar functionality